# draw cube into 3D scatterplot in RGL

Tags: r, 3d, plot, cube, rgl

I'm trying to add a smaller cube/mesh (with specified side length) to a 3D scatterplot. I'd like for the cube to be positioned at the origin. How would I go about doing that? I've played around with         cube3d() but I can't seem to position the cube right nor make it a mesh (so I can see the data points it contains. Here's what I have:

```
library(rgl)
x <- runif(100)
y <- runif(100)
z <- runif(100)
plot3d(x,y,z, type="p", col="red", xlab="x", ylab="y", zlab="z", site=5, lwd=15)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a `cube3d` function that by default returns a list object (but does not plot it) that represents a cube spanning x:[-1,1]; y:[-1,1]; z:[-1,1]. If you apply a color to the sides, it will be solid by default. You need to make the sides transparent with 'alpha" (see `?rgl.materials`). So if we start out with the plot you used:

```
library(rgl)
x <- runif(100)
y <- runif(100)
z <- runif(100)
plot3d(x,y,z, type="p", col="red", xlab="x", ylab="y", zlab="z", site=5, lwd=15)
c3d <- cube3d(color="red", alpha=0.1)  # nothing happens yet
c3d   # Look at structure
shade3d(c3d)   # render the object
```

This expands the plot to the default dimensions of the transparent red cube mentioned above. The vertices are at the xyz location in the first three rows of the $vb element:

```
c3b$vb
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1   -1    1
[2,]   -1   -1    1    1   -1   -1    1    1
[3,]   -1   -1   -1   -1    1    1    1    1
[4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
```

Now to make another cube that has one of its vertices at the origin, the quickest way I could think of was to set all the -1's to 0:

```
 c3d.origin <- cube3d(color="red", alpha=0.1)
 c3d.origin$vb [c3d.origin$vb == -1] <- 0
 shade3d(c3d.origin)
 rgl.snapshot("cubes3d.png")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I had around for various purposes. It should get you started.

```
box <- data.frame(
    x = c(1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1),
    y = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1),
    z = c(1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1))
segments3d(box$x, box$y, box$z, line_antialias = TRUE, col = "blue")
points3d(0,0,0, col = "red", size = 5, point_antialias = TRUE)
```

Comment: That helps thanks! I'm now trying to position the box in one of the corners of the plot. Do you know how I would do that?

Comment: Well, my example box runs from -1 to 1 across x, y, z with the red dot at 0,0,0, so the box is a 2x unit cube.  Do you want to translate it so that the corner of the cube is at 0,0,0 (I'm not sure from what you've said)?  If so, do `box <- box + 1` then replot.  Or something similar depending upon where you want it.  Note that in the example, the coordinates are lined up vertically so you draw from 1,1,1 to -1,1,1, then 1,1,1 to 1,1,-1 (in pairs)