# Plot a customized cube/box with coordinates into a larger plot3d / plot3drgl plot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, 3d

I make a 3D Plot with the sizes -5 to 5 for x, y and z and add a point at (0, 0, 0):

```r
library(plot3D)
library(plot3Drgl)
library(rgl)

points3D(0,0,0, xlim=c(-5,5), ylim=c(-5,5), zlim=c(-5,5), type = "p", plot=F)
plotrgl()
```

No I want to highlight a special area within this plot with a smaller cube/box.
The following coordinates should define the space:

```r
xlow = -4.95
xhigh = 4.67

ylow = -3.77
yhigh = 4.88

zlow = -3.34
zhigh = 2.85
```

I tried to come up with the solution based on this:

[draw cube into 3D scatterplot in RGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162354/draw-cube-into-3d-scatterplot-in-rgl)

[Draw multiple 3D boxes of different dimensions and coordinates in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238112/draw-multiple-3d-boxes-of-different-dimensions-and-coordinates-in-r)

But I can't customize it to my case.

Do you have any idea how I can easily add this smaller box into my 3D plot?